# ggplot: how to add multiple legends for plot and vertical lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I've created a plot which shows the means of two groups and associated 95% confidence band, as below. For the plot, I've already used different line types, fillings, colors.

The data `plot_band` is as follows.

```
dput(plot_band)
structure(list(mean = c(0.0909296772008702, 0.0949102886382386, 
0.0989192140983566, 0.102428753920507, 0.106190021551613, 0.109834234007574, 
0.11282406874623, 0.116443987192088, 0.119646042014149, 0.122877131667032, 
0.125734341129646, 0.129194412319665, 0.131921946416482, 0.13467000293138, 
0.137801823091921, 0.140320771073742, 0.143300871011905, 0.145703574224808, 
0.148502607395268, 0.151216269559201, 0.153957673466713, 0.15642722394871, 
0.159399752204122, 0.16158535629103, 0.163992551285173, 0.166446319141126, 
0.168796463238069, 0.17130024918415, 0.17319290052143, 0.175970079857704, 
0.178037138778032, 0.180359643729028, 0.182563083353043, 0.184882067722455, 
0.186933337196788, 0.18928611634363, 0.19095095692481, 0.193552969255731, 
0.195137836881874, 0.197581990963152, 0.199824696342001, 0.201576167030431, 
0.203292777876833, 0.205785273925517, 0.207611128924057, 0.209067294675698, 
0.211624327477106, 0.213018027996152, 0.215073900329166, 0.21654896049152, 
0.218432328738047, 0.220299232072702, 0.221520169903876, 0.224082916931098, 
0.225373663731495, 0.227623092060467, 0.228971037740905, 0.230665903341562, 
0.232255049713341, 0.233816039663021, 0.236156033603955, 0.237722706454038, 
0.239326639984125, 0.241061288510212, 0.323782287073584, 0.325539303794681, 
0.326575563604555, 0.327932235745535, 0.329326904419804, 0.330270965006864, 
0.331794972975829, 0.332736401387824, 0.333736983920265, 0.334858878358806, 
0.335995344145518, 0.336884010919713, 0.337760950823761, 0.338470035342276, 
0.339694375762279, 0.340590586642847, 0.340934410282471, 0.342186505998774, 
0.342699699846757, 0.343822718137376, 0.344352069575663, 0.345191547743302, 
0.345986783878912, 0.346908459064914, 0.347636673707646, 0.3483601957891, 
0.349017016236978, 0.349393026672962, 0.350215046428817, 0.350578051082168, 
0.351357872622786, 0.351833990930714, 0.352451422717008, 0.352852417773313, 
0.353786047124291, 0.354360144310735, 0.354804607588953, 0.355216156665893, 
0.3556114518015, 0.356570758245453, 0.357097049535425, 0.357671243406622, 
0.35787930232607, 0.358500009058086, 0.359107586207553, 0.359418346394681, 
0.359923090516015, 0.360327770652831, 0.360646653761867, 0.361526704703965, 
0.361860340596181, 0.362284616802613, 0.362408547406209, 0.363068975461424, 
0.363173638916247, 0.363746165222553, 0.364318465554143, 0.364550369183249, 
0.365263491228022, 0.365588246738469, 0.366124420845147, 0.366327320718437, 
0.366730809501062, 0.367298014408034), p2.5 = c(0.00920236578162877, 
0.0111305911426958, 0.0131257550019632, 0.015586474005665, 0.017588259827762, 
0.0195835240844649, 0.021653464115484, 0.0245221378289171, 0.0263028370478539, 
0.0283125178459841, 0.030809139661692, 0.034224299031932, 0.0351514351131448, 
0.0374690177003245, 0.0401208217539481, 0.0416432632702995, 0.0436268495854353, 
0.0455924496480308, 0.0481710615607138, 0.0498487868097217, 0.052013860735697, 
0.0541864115090449, 0.0559355297931858, 0.0582185384506931, 0.0595049507852038, 
0.0617291057747846, 0.0624904066599628, 0.064090526611587, 0.0665855608482458, 
0.0681610015253132, 0.0689510143842853, 0.0714235246023074, 0.0730718365551066, 
0.0733828347805513, 0.0749772653575311, 0.0775677990166739, 0.0782434582066251, 
0.0809696065399504, 0.0800620502625316, 0.0822097262074474, 0.0837314882447324, 
0.0836800886932387, 0.0843305338836378, 0.0862036703259026, 0.0874082656018874, 
0.0881312854081838, 0.0887921830279765, 0.0892805555426737, 0.0901061351380764, 
0.0914750995958728, 0.0913838119125662, 0.0926827936869315, 0.0929511644196126, 
0.0940218350370357, 0.0944327299872979, 0.0953545299910439, 0.0948298565703383, 
0.0957001873318579, 0.0961251564147676, 0.0971098251546806, 0.0974911491380601, 
0.0986598120212823, 0.0982370236835561, 0.0987719638365328, 0.114148199394403, 
0.125138552629865, 0.133069438084806, 0.140931059768343, 0.147647282172844, 
0.155831735418124, 0.163154010787227, 0.16809087346053, 0.173413948644787, 
0.178336300631342, 0.183561163161725, 0.189552221591194, 0.192350001446747, 
0.19547327255232, 0.19824967633061, 0.202611107184988, 0.205071997319457, 
0.206232495037667, 0.208471493073236, 0.209717390943683, 0.211692880593303, 
0.213829033311537, 0.215383413348152, 0.216370831366554, 0.216980537940184, 
0.217670415960084, 0.218147500129008, 0.219104770868165, 0.220215949003459, 
0.219501167154474, 0.219635297722562, 0.220565169003312, 0.218821371303922, 
0.218910618214851, 0.219518190869959, 0.219204079206471, 0.219448334243776, 
0.219174641398391, 0.217619259716122, 0.217993716481521, 0.218343413130982, 
0.217141573568049, 0.216438618727695, 0.215672180354215, 0.214841486865522, 
0.214092486614703, 0.216084004877199, 0.213891621307228, 0.213397326450924, 
0.212530621813324, 0.212650230928244, 0.211323326285971, 0.211512467761759, 
0.209879967307571, 0.208388878793908, 0.209257043929222, 0.207665115418059, 
0.207413292377895, 0.204980142991601, 0.206053394727878, 0.205039712521127, 
0.203155679138143, 0.202289445844638, 0.201779149557556), p97.5 = c(0.240681337890249, 
0.239988615023241, 0.239222274397932, 0.23882694927308, 0.239567463457127, 
0.240035884370459, 0.239971640602537, 0.242348644629734, 0.244241554912481, 
0.246794068956881, 0.248869825514075, 0.252843804762058, 0.254595507587193, 
0.257498240756364, 0.26074636531938, 0.263991307688752, 0.268222101449506, 
0.270245299020079, 0.278955701793892, 0.280366963871541, 0.286253886155709, 
0.290942761721134, 0.29709853936211, 0.300641051539586, 0.307350564223005, 
0.314475951046524, 0.31757563389217, 0.324250050938626, 0.326645521042049, 
0.334746718583917, 0.341297900171566, 0.347056902406046, 0.352412986039391, 
0.356409285744598, 0.364329251893085, 0.36882469705109, 0.373595444661095, 
0.379308956442793, 0.388012909521406, 0.393418480355642, 0.399407258087214, 
0.403270925317011, 0.407517084163824, 0.413742327029277, 0.42089783652825, 
0.422996679448412, 0.430738094720356, 0.433915405828653, 0.438263395419797, 
0.442376801773873, 0.450664409546504, 0.453854917168461, 0.455755257192578, 
0.463879371708031, 0.470262095557133, 0.478816677993115, 0.478998770025097, 
0.485204929246363, 0.490588733478761, 0.49747652543363, 0.498792119487052, 
0.508008619470507, 0.51314092048762, 0.518568532547669, 0.579810955268174, 
0.563256045407579, 0.55093710586083, 0.541241619905278, 0.532667775608687, 
0.523824194956849, 0.518816497858615, 0.512618467188886, 0.506452368044292, 
0.501653171003674, 0.499276681561068, 0.496002704329641, 0.494256887981196, 
0.49200837587611, 0.490570113245846, 0.491077058931435, 0.487352049845066, 
0.487927727831147, 0.487928022062059, 0.488900063808496, 0.488866145012628, 
0.489808465409391, 0.491100206396406, 0.492044173457154, 0.494346147046575, 
0.494980820850837, 0.49616843086841, 0.497216550345458, 0.499201695431901, 
0.501160614633382, 0.502598288902507, 0.504203085629905, 0.50530488873578, 
0.508449115699177, 0.508914783054669, 0.51306711977087, 0.51479783743171, 
0.51648055644086, 0.518549503653961, 0.522859455223989, 0.522598786005884, 
0.52736459871623, 0.527054294078792, 0.532359397607223, 0.532643025946804, 
0.533817320437782, 0.535862852499484, 0.539613602346564, 0.54138065631686, 
0.544340213112881, 0.545596882887723, 0.549029532028693, 0.546769636775625, 
0.551728290583129, 0.552996735997194, 0.555676593069663, 0.559580922687426, 
0.561700216317917, 0.562726465369815, 0.563527127546323, 0.567715046522725, 
0.568850181180136, 0.56965258128659, 0.571847219713553), outcome = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("DLT", 
"CB"), class = "factor"), exp_X_post = c(721.595263503532, 794.40305777437, 
865.319646465533, 933.669956578678, 999.728550839186, 1062.12810757171, 
1121.92986212885, 1186.37187215809, 1246.1267376175, 1305.33376392859, 
1359.36602305224, 1421.23758898206, 1472.44041133326, 1520.62395309786, 
1584.09764621781, 1634.01654454251, 1685.34860459111, 1735.26374323406, 
1785.87871337346, 1840.42999799797, 1888.32905203148, 1937.38674685726, 
1990.74583676908, 2041.61942276328, 2083.76909363497, 2134.07414000003, 
2177.97560514382, 2227.25787768033, 2269.76501622686, 2319.50659548171, 
2360.78992430352, 2404.37623851091, 2449.36656617313, 2500.80748523146, 
2540.71467060956, 2588.5685157055, 2630.93535458068, 2675.04099554242, 
2709.53185769419, 2763.12669881888, 2807.24737149465, 2849.03542063784, 
2887.16961904492, 2927.78459960731, 2973.91123171086, 3006.0197134382, 
3056.06581532434, 3089.41001229951, 3132.29020081068, 3177.35838641843, 
3212.66669292569, 3256.19625640177, 3284.73766167032, 3330.28770837953, 
3368.28973519186, 3409.05190043795, 3449.93435443996, 3485.59367731521, 
3524.70884576068, 3557.60265444533, 3615.06476720162, 3648.55074883409, 
3688.13510762386, 3727.38208940522, 721.595263503532, 794.40305777437, 
865.319646465533, 933.669956578678, 999.728550839186, 1062.12810757171, 
1121.92986212885, 1186.37187215809, 1246.1267376175, 1305.33376392859, 
1359.36602305224, 1421.23758898206, 1472.44041133326, 1520.62395309786, 
1584.09764621781, 1634.01654454251, 1685.34860459111, 1735.26374323406, 
1785.87871337346, 1840.42999799797, 1888.32905203148, 1937.38674685726, 
1990.74583676908, 2041.61942276328, 2083.76909363497, 2134.07414000003, 
2177.97560514382, 2227.25787768033, 2269.76501622686, 2319.50659548171, 
2360.78992430352, 2404.37623851091, 2449.36656617313, 2500.80748523146, 
2540.71467060956, 2588.5685157055, 2630.93535458068, 2675.04099554242, 
2709.53185769419, 2763.12669881888, 2807.24737149465, 2849.03542063784, 
2887.16961904492, 2927.78459960731, 2973.91123171086, 3006.0197134382, 
3056.06581532434, 3089.41001229951, 3132.29020081068, 3177.35838641843, 
3212.66669292569, 3256.19625640177, 3284.73766167032, 3330.28770837953, 
3368.28973519186, 3409.05190043795, 3449.93435443996, 3485.59367731521, 
3524.70884576068, 3557.60265444533, 3615.06476720162, 3648.55074883409, 
3688.13510762386, 3727.38208940522)), .Names = c("mean", "p2.5", 
"p97.5", "outcome", "exp_X_post"), row.names = c("pi_A[1]", "pi_A[2]", 
"pi_A[3]", "pi_A[4]", "pi_A[5]", "pi_A[6]", "pi_A[7]", "pi_A[8]", 
"pi_A[9]", "pi_A[10]", "pi_A[11]", "pi_A[12]", "pi_A[13]", "pi_A[14]", 
"pi_A[15]", "pi_A[16]", "pi_A[17]", "pi_A[18]", "pi_A[19]", "pi_A[20]", 
"pi_A[21]", "pi_A[22]", "pi_A[23]", "pi_A[24]", "pi_A[25]", "pi_A[26]", 
"pi_A[27]", "pi_A[28]", "pi_A[29]", "pi_A[30]", "pi_A[31]", "pi_A[32]", 
"pi_A[33]", "pi_A[34]", "pi_A[35]", "pi_A[36]", "pi_A[37]", "pi_A[38]", 
"pi_A[39]", "pi_A[40]", "pi_A[41]", "pi_A[42]", "pi_A[43]", "pi_A[44]", 
"pi_A[45]", "pi_A[46]", "pi_A[47]", "pi_A[48]", "pi_A[49]", "pi_A[50]", 
"pi_A[51]", "pi_A[52]", "pi_A[53]", "pi_A[54]", "pi_A[55]", "pi_A[56]", 
"pi_A[57]", "pi_A[58]", "pi_A[59]", "pi_A[60]", "pi_A[61]", "pi_A[62]", 
"pi_A[63]", "pi_A[64]", "qi_A[1]", "qi_A[2]", "qi_A[3]", "qi_A[4]", 
"qi_A[5]", "qi_A[6]", "qi_A[7]", "qi_A[8]", "qi_A[9]", "qi_A[10]", 
"qi_A[11]", "qi_A[12]", "qi_A[13]", "qi_A[14]", "qi_A[15]", "qi_A[16]", 
"qi_A[17]", "qi_A[18]", "qi_A[19]", "qi_A[20]", "qi_A[21]", "qi_A[22]", 
"qi_A[23]", "qi_A[24]", "qi_A[25]", "qi_A[26]", "qi_A[27]", "qi_A[28]", 
"qi_A[29]", "qi_A[30]", "qi_A[31]", "qi_A[32]", "qi_A[33]", "qi_A[34]", 
"qi_A[35]", "qi_A[36]", "qi_A[37]", "qi_A[38]", "qi_A[39]", "qi_A[40]", 
"qi_A[41]", "qi_A[42]", "qi_A[43]", "qi_A[44]", "qi_A[45]", "qi_A[46]", 
"qi_A[47]", "qi_A[48]", "qi_A[49]", "qi_A[50]", "qi_A[51]", "qi_A[52]", 
"qi_A[53]", "qi_A[54]", "qi_A[55]", "qi_A[56]", "qi_A[57]", "qi_A[58]", 
"qi_A[59]", "qi_A[60]", "qi_A[61]", "qi_A[62]", "qi_A[63]", "qi_A[64]"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Now I want to add some vertical dashed lines. I wish to use different color for each vertical line and have legend for those lines as well. The information for those vertical lines are in another data frame `observed_mean`:

```
dput(observed_mean)
structure(list(TRT = structure(1:9, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"), class = "factor"), gmcmin = c(967.117632548, 
1306.76729845833, 2394.519441584, 2404.73065902857, 3047.48745766364, 
2550.12866139, 1863.6505272925, 3569.57489109, 3660.40695204)), .Names = c("TRT", 
"gmcmin"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the code to generate the plot:

```
range <- range(plot_band$exp_X_post)
range <- c(floor(range[1]), ceiling(range[2]))
step <- floor((range[2] - range[1]) / 10)

ggplot(plot_band, aes(x = exp_X_post, y = mean, 
                              color = outcome, linetype = outcome)) + 
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = p2.5, ymax = p97.5, linetype = NA,
                    fill = outcome), 
                alpha = 0.4) +
    geom_line(size = 1.5) + 
    xlab("Exposure") +
    ylab("Proability of CB/DLT") +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = range,
                       breaks = seq(range[1], range[2], by = step)
                       ) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = observed_mean$gmcmin,
               linetype = 'longdash') +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position = 'top',
          plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 3, 1), "lines"),
          legend.title = element_text(size = 15),
          axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(0, 15, 0, 0))) +
    scale_color_discrete(name = "Probability (95% CI)") +
    scale_fill_discrete(name = "Probability (95% CI)") +
    scale_linetype_discrete(name = "Probability (95% CI)")
```

**Note: the last three lines are used to change the legend title from variable name `outcome` to "Probability (95% CI)". NOT sure whether that's the right way though.**

**Questions:**

1. I wish to put the current legend to the right, then below that I'd like to put the legend for vertical lines. Could anyone give me some clues how to do that?
2. As shown in the plot, there are two identical (not same color though) legends on top. The one below comes out if I change the order of the factor `outcome` with following code. I am not sure why that happens. How could I get rid of that?

   plot_band$outcome <- factor(plot_band$outcome, levels = c("DLT", "CB"))

Thanks a lot for any comments/suggestions!!

[image]

Comment: Instead of including the output of `str(plot_band)`, it is better and more convenient to include the output of `dput(plot_band)`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed to ``dput(plot_band)``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra legend box is showing up because of the `linetype = NA` in the `aes()` of `geom_ribbon` moving the linetype out of the mapping will take care of that.

For the line labeling, you can perhaps just put the labels on the plot using `geom_text`

Here is a full plot that does something like that (now with ggrepel to place the labels more sensibly -- can't believe I didn't start there)

```
# install.packages("devtools")
# devtools::install_github("slowkow/ggrepel")
library(ggrepel)


ggplot(plot_band, aes(x = exp_X_post, y = mean, 
                      color = outcome, linetype = outcome)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = p2.5, ymax = p97.5,
                  fill = outcome), 
              alpha = 0.4
              , linetype = "blank") +
  geom_line(size = 1.5) + 
  xlab("Exposure") +
  ylab("Proability of CB/DLT") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = range,
                     breaks = seq(range[1], range[2], by = step)
  ) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = observed_mean$gmcmin
             , linetype = 'longdash') +
  geom_text_repel(
     mapping = aes(
        x = gmcmin
        , y = 0
        , label = TRT
        , color = NA
        , linetype = NA)
     , data = observed_mean
     , show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = 'top',
        plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 3, 1), "lines"),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(0, 15, 0, 0))) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Probability (95% CI)") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Probability (95% CI)") +
  scale_linetype_discrete(name = "Probability (95% CI)")
```

(Note: the mean labels overlap, so you may need to more careful position those, e.g., by adding another column to `observed_mean` giving the position where you want them plotted).

If you need the labels to be in a legend instead, you can use this code:

```
ggplot(plot_band, aes(x = exp_X_post, y = mean, 
                      color = outcome)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = p2.5, ymax = p97.5,
                  fill = outcome), 
              alpha = 0.4
              , linetype = "blank") +
  geom_line(#aes(linetype = outcome)
            #,
              size = 1.5
            # , show.legend = FALSE
            ) + 
  xlab("Exposure") +
  ylab("Proability of CB/DLT") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty(range)) +
  geom_vline(
    mapping = aes(xintercept = gmcmin
                  , linetype = TRT)
    , data = observed_mean) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = 'right',
        plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 3, 1), "lines"),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(0, 15, 0, 0))) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Probability (95% CI)") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Probability (95% CI)") +
  scale_linetype_discrete(name = "Treatment")
```

Note, that I removed the linetype from the main lines, as it was causing some weirdness with the vertical line. You can add it back by uncommenting the parts in `geom_line()` but note that it then shows up in the list with the treatments. There is probably a way to fix that if you absolutely need it, but my quick tries aren't working. I will note, however, that the linetypes are a bit hard to pick out.

[Example plot with both the legend and the labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsmUr.png)

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback! That's helpful. I prefer to put the labels to the right as legend because: (1) and as you said, the mean labels overlap; (2) the data will change case by case. It's then not practical to adjust the positions of the labels. With that said, is there a way to plot mean labels as legend to the right of the plot??

Comment: Yep -- see my latest edit(s). I also added a better way to automate placement of the labels directly on the plot using `ggrepel` -- I should have thought of that sooner, but don't use many (enough?) labels on my plots.

Comment: Wow, Thanks a ton, Mark!! BTW, before I posted for help, I also observed the "weirdness" if I wish to have different line types for both main lines and vertical lines. Anyway, your plot looks good enough to me! Also it's good to know ``ggrepel``.